# Git checkout - how to

Tags: git, version-control, branch

I have just cloned a repository locally. We are expected to always work out of develop branch that is already part of the repository. When I list all the branches as follows:

```
git branch -a
```

The results are as follows:

```
master (with an *)
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/develop
remotes/origin/master
```

How do I now checkout the develop branch and start working.
When I just say

```
git checkout

Checking out files: 100% (2436/2436), done.
Note: checking out 'develop'.
enter code here`
enter code here`You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, 
make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
```

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example

```
git checkout -b new_branch_name
```

If I checkout using, it seems to be creating a new local branch

```
git checkout -b new_branch_name
```

The other option that comes to mind is

```
git checkout -b develop origin/develop
```

It is obvious that I am missing some fundamental understanding of Git branches.
I would like clarification on the above issue and also how branch works when we have branches already on the remote.

Comment: "we are expected", I would assume you would get on-the-job training on how to use the required tools, you should go check with your team lead to see what options exists for this kind of training.

Comment: @user2186453, is there any answer helps you solve the problem? If yes, please mark it since it will help oyhers who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

to checkout remote branch you should hit

```
git checkout remote_branch_name
```

If you want to switch to a local branch

```
git checkout -b local_branch_name
```

Read more about it [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

Answer (score 0):

Actually all the branches reference is exist in `.git/refs/remotes directory`. You can directly switch to different branches. Such as `git checkout develop`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a local branch that is tracking the remote branch:

```
git checkout -b local_brach_name origin/remote_brach_name
```

For example:

```
git checkout -b develop origin/develop
```

Will create a local branch named develop tracking the remote branch with the same name (the command will also checkout to this new local branch).

Comment: Sorry if this is a basic question. So, why should I "create" a local branch at all. The branch already exists in the repository and I have cloned it.

Comment: @user2186453 In git you cannot work directly on a remote branch, you must have your own local copy. From your output, you cloned the master branch, for which git created a local copy for you. If you had cloned the develop branch, git would have created a local copy of it for you, always tracking the remote. You can check your local branches with `git branch`. The [docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) might help you with better understanding how remote branches work.

Answer (score 0):

i think both answers are right, but just in case a bit of gitHelp :p .

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/develop
remotes/origin/master
```

- git branch  ---> create a new LOCAL branch
- git checkout  ---> use it to move between branches
- git checkout -b  ---> create and move to new LOCAL branch.
  (equivalent to branch + checkout)

Now as soon as you clone the repo, you will be able to "`git checkout develop`" because the remote branch already exist when you clone the repo, then you dont "necesary" need to `git branch develop && git checkout develop`.

Another comment just to avoid confiusing is: when you clone a repo, it JUST create master LOCAL branch. (i mean, if you git clone and git branch, you will see master*) All the remote branches are available, but you allways need to `git checkout <name>` in order to code in that branch. (remember, if the remotebranch exist you can simple git checkout , if not, you will need to create locally and then push it if you want)